# How to convert png to jpg in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

On iOS, CameraOptions EncodingType is being ignored. The following options will save a photo as PNG, despite setting EncodingOptions to JPEG:

```js
const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 80,
      correctOrientation: true,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      targetWidth: 700,
      targetHeight: 1000
    }
```

To circumvent this issue, I imagine it should be possible to convert the PNG file to JPEG. How can I do this within Ionic?